# How Clojure Cond macro works

Tags: clojure, macros

I am fairly comfortable with Clojure but have always shied away from macros.  In an attempt to remedy that, I'm reading through "Mastering Clojure Macros" and also looking at some Clojure core macros generally.

While reading over the `cond` macro, I got a little tripped up as to what is actually being evaluated when.  Assuming `clauses` is not nil and that the initial `when` test passes, we then evaluate the list call.  List is a function, so it must first evaluate all of it's arguments before entering it's body.  The first argument is just the symbol `'if`, the next argument is then `(first  claues)` which evaluates to the first test, but then the part I found a bit confusing is what happens with the next (3rd) argument.  It looks like the entire form:

```
(if (next clauses)
    (second clauses)
    (throw (IllegalArgumentException.
            "cond requires an even number of forms")))
```

is actually evaluated before the final macroexpansion is returned for evaluation.  If this is correct, does that mean that the test for an even number of forms occurs before the macro is actually expanded, and therefore can bail with an exception before the macro has actually generated a list for evaluation at runtime?

```
(defmacro cond
  "Takes a set of test/expr pairs. It evaluates each test one at a
  time.  If a test returns logical true, cond evaluates and returns
  the value of the corresponding expr and doesn't evaluate any of the
  other tests or exprs. (cond) returns nil."
  {:added "1.0"}
  [& clauses]
    (when clauses
      (list 'if (first clauses)
            (if (next clauses)
                (second clauses)
                (throw (IllegalArgumentException.
                         "cond requires an even number of forms")))
            (cons 'clojure.core/cond (next (next clauses))))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to see how a macro works is to check it with [`clojure.core/macroexpand-1`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/macroexpand-1) or [`clojure.walk/macroexpand-all`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.walk/macroexpand-all).

We can for example see how the following form will be expanded:

```
(cond
  (pos? 1) :positive
  (neg? -1) :negative)
```

with `macroexpand-1`:

```
(macroexpand-1
  '(cond
    (pos? 1) :positive
    (neg? -1) :negative))

;; => (if (pos? 1) :positive (clojure.core/cond (neg? -1) :negative))
```

We can see that when that form is expanded, `clauses` is bound to the sequence of these expressions: `(pos? 1)`, `:positive`, `(neg? -1)` and `:negative`.

`(first clauses)` will evaluate to `(pos? 1)` and its value will be used as the test expression for the emitted `if`. Then the macro checks if the first predicate has its required result expression by checking if it has more than one clause: `(next clauses)` will evaluate to `(:positive (neg? -1) :negative)` which is truthy and the true branch of the emitted `if` will get the value of `(second clauses)` which is `:positive`.

The else branch of the emitted `if` will get `(clojure.core/cond (neg? -1) :negative)`. As the emitted code will again include a call to `cond` macro, it will be called again and expanded again.

To see the fully expanded code we can use `clojure.walk/macroexpand-all`:

```
(require 'clojure.walk)

(clojure.walk/macroexpand-all
      '(cond
        (pos? 1) :positive
        (neg? -1) :negative))
;; => (if (pos? 1) :positive (if (neg? -1) :negative nil))
```

To expand on the topic if the forms included in `clauses` are evaluated during macro expansion, we can inject some side effects into the code:

```
(clojure.walk/macroexpand-all
  '(cond
     (do
       (println "(pos? 1) evaluated!")
       (pos? 1))
     (do
       (println ":positive evaluated1")
       :positive)

     (do
       (println "(neg? -1) evaluated!")
       (neg? -1))
     (do
       (println ":negative evaluated!")
       :negative)))
=>
(if
 (do (println "(pos? 1) evaluated!") (pos? 1))
 (do (println ":positive evaluated1") :positive)
 (if (do (println "(neg? -1) evaluated!") (neg? -1)) (do (println ":negative evaluated!") :negative) nil))
```

As we can see no side effects were executed because none of the clauses were evaluated during macro expansion.

We can also check if the call to `throw` is evaluated during macro expansion by providing `clauses` that will cause the else branch of the `(if (next clauses) ...` to be called:

```
(macroexpand-1 '(cond (pos? 1)))
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: cond requires an even number of forms
```

Here we can see that the exception was thrown and macro expansion of the `cond` macro didn't complete normally by returning the macro expanded code. The reason the `throw` form is evaluated during macro expansion is it is not quoted (e.g. ``(throw ...)`).

Comment: Thanks for your reply Piotrek!  I am aware of `macroexpand-1` and `macroexpand`, but they show me the result of the expansion, not what occurs when.  My question was more asking if the third argument to `list` (the if form) in the macro body is evaluated prior to the final macro-expanded list being returned for runtime evaluation.  It seems like before the expansion is even built up, the check is performed for `(next clauses)`.  E.G. the check for `(next clauses)` in the inner `if` is actually evaluated prior to the outer `if` which tests `(first clauses)`.

Comment: None of the forms of the `clauses` is evaluated during macro expansion. E.g. `(next clauses)` checks if the sequence containing all the clauses has more than one elements but without actual evaluation of these clauses (they are simple data elements like a list of symbols - `'(pos? 1)` or a keyword `:positive`). But the form `(pos? 1)` is not evaluated during macro expansion.

Comment: I have updated my answer to cover if/when clauses are evaluated during macro expansion.

Comment: I appreciate your responses, but my question is very specific and I'm likely not asking it very well.  What I'm wondering is ...does the illegal argument `if` test occur before the macro is expanded. It must be because for `:positive` to even be returned from the `if`, the test `(next clauses)` must be evaluated.  The more I type this out and think about it, the more I feel the answer is obviously yes and I'm wondering why I even had the question to begin with!  Sometimes the process of formally asking the question gets you to the answer I guess.

Comment: Oh, now I get your question :) Yes, the call to `throw` will be evaluated during macroexpansion. You can prove it by passing code with `cond` receiving odd number of clauses. Let me add it to my answer.

Comment: Right - and that test actually occurs even before `(list 'if (first clauses) ...` since this test wouldn't happen until the macro was fully expanded.  I think I just found the order confusing upon first  encounter ...

Comment: Yes, all arguments to `(list ...`) call must be evaluated first so the throw will happen before the `list` function will be called with all the arguments.